# Issues updating BindingList every second with DispatchingTimer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bindinglist with an ExpireTime which is a date, I then use a converter to convert it to a timespan so I can show how long until ExpireTime

```
private BindingList<PlayerSearchResultTransfer> _transferlistItems;
public BindingList<PlayerSearchResultTransfer> TransferlistItems
{
    get { return _transferlistItems; }
    set { _transferlistItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TransferlistItems);}
}

private readonly DispatcherTimer _uiTimer;

public TransferListViewModel(IPlayerSearchQuery playerSearchQuery)
{
    _uiTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _uiTimer.Tick += (s, e) => RaisePropertyChanged("ExpireTime");
    _uiTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    _uiTimer.Start();
}
```

and the class I am binding against

```
public class PlayerSearchResultTransfer : PlayerSearchResult
{
    private DateTime _expireTime;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DateTime ExpireTime
    {
        get { return _expireTime; }
        set
        {
            _expireTime = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ExpireTime");
        }
    }
```

My WPF

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:TimeRemainingConverter x:Key="TimeRemainingConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TransferlistItems}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Name" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Name" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Expires" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExpireTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeRemainingConverter}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bid" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BidValue}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Buyout" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BuyoutValue}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my converter

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(TimeSpan))]    
public class TimeRemainingConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
        var timespan = dateTime - DateTime.Now;

        return timespan < new TimeSpan(1000)
            ? new TimeSpan(0)
            : new TimeSpan(timespan.Hours, timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Solution**
Had forgot to add INotifyPropertyChanged to my PlayerSearchResultTransfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are raising `PropertyChanged` event on ViewModel class. It should be raised on every instance of `PlayerSearchResultTransfer` for converter to fire for all items.

```
_uiTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    foreach (PlayerSearchResultTransfer player in TransferlistItems)
    {
        player.RaisePropertyChanged("ExpireTime");
    }
};
```

Also, make sure `PlayerSearchResultTransfer` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to let GUI refresh on any property change.

Comment: That makes alot of sense to od it on each object, but it didnt change anything, still not changing the shown timespan

Comment: I tried in small sample and it works for me though. Try place a breakpoint on getter of `ExpireTime` and see if it gets hit.

Comment: And you are using a bindinglist and using the converter?

Comment: Yes exact same code with simple `TestClass` containing property `ExpireTime` only.

Comment: Could you maybe upload that testproject somwhere? Then I might be able to spot the difference, seems really strange

Comment: Download it from here - [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=89D0A48E0EFB8E82!112&authkey=!AG8Xt1UDFN6DeNg&ithint=file%2c.zip).

Comment: Are you able to access it and validate?

Comment: I found it, I forgot to add INotifyPropertyChanged to my model

Comment: Oh.. I will update it in answer as well so that it can help others as well.